# Paste using middle mouse button

Tags: windows-7, shortcuts, hotkeys, productivity

Is there any application to paste the same text every time with middle button?

I have seen tools to paste the clipboard text, But I am looking to paste the same text every time I click the middle button of my mouse.

Comment: In most applications the middle mouse button is a reserved hotkey. In Office it activates mouse scroll and in browsers it opens a link in a new tab. Can you use a keyboard shortcut instead?

Comment: Also, can detail what you mean by post the same text? Do you want to have the user define this, or will it always be the same words, programmed in?

Comment: I need to paste the text in firefox, Keyboard shortcut taking a bit time and its faster to go with mouse. 
I want to have this as user defined and the same text needs to be pasted every time.

Comment: So you want to create a new function, to allow middle-mouse to paste text from a bespoke location, rather than from the clipboard? Will this be a Firefox plugin or extension? It would help if you could explain why you want to do this. Sorry for all the questions, but you're more likely to get a good answer if your question provides all the info needed.

Comment: A predefined text? Hmm, thats sad. I just found [AutoCopy](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/autocopy/) (Firefox Extension) which pastes with middle-click the current selected text. I guess, that doesn't fit your needs 100%?

Comment: I am gonna use firefox only so there wont be problem if it s plugin or extension from firefox and I am OK if any other tool provides the same feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this is easy to achieve with [**AutoHotkey**](http://www.autohotkey.com):

```
SetTitleMatchMode 2
#IfWinActive Firefox
  MButton::
    SendInput Hello World!
    Return
#IfWinActive
```

Install AHK, save the above in a text file with .AHK extension, then run the script.

Comment: Thank You , This is what I am looking for. It is extremely wonderful.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use [Makro Toolworks](http://www.macrotoolworks.com/index.php/de/macro-automation-software/macro-toolworks-automation-macros), it lets you record or create key or mouse inputs and execute them with any mouse/keyboard button you like.